# How to add emoji to DataTable loading

Tags: javascript, emoji

I have the following code for setting up a DataTable. The table is large so display of data is not instant. The code previously used font-awesome for displaying a spinning cog but I don't want to use font-awesome but an emoji. How do I add an emoji of a spinning cog to the following code?

```
//⚙️
var table = $('#lTable').DataTable({
//other setup stuff
"language": {
                "processing": "Table is loading...",                
            }
      }
});
```

This was my font-awesome line

```
"processing": "<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i><span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span>",
```

I am quite new to html so unsure how to do this.

Thank you :)

I wish for it to look a bit like this (but cog is spinning)

[image]